# Xamarin forms (Cross-Platform) : Multiple type of cells in ListView

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I am new to Xamarin. I have a requirement where I have to implement a ListView or say tableView that have multiple different type-size cells.
And I also have to add Header for a particular section of cells, and some of my custom cells have a horizontal scroll in it. [image: Here I attached the image for my listview requirement.]

I have done this thing in iOS native UITableView before, but don't know how this done in Xamarin cross platform, can anyone help me out this?

Comment: use DataTemplateSelector in listView or use tableView

Comment: @ColeXia do you know how can I set different heights for different DataTemplateSelector? And How can I implement one DataTemplateSelector with horizontal scrolling?

Comment: 1. set listView.HasUnevenRowsDifferent = true. and define the different dataTemplate.   2. set scrollview with horizontal oritation inside the dataTemplate

Comment: Oh yes thanks, listView.HasUnevenRowsDifferent works fine. Now I am looking for one cell with horizontal scrolling.

Comment: try this plugin :https://blog.xamarin.com/flip-through-items-with-xamarin-forms-carouselview/

Answer (score 21):

You are looking for `DataTemplateSelector`, which is very well documented in the official [Xamarin.Forms documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector/).

The basics are that you create your own `DataTemplateSelector` class:

```
public class MyDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{

}
```

In that class you override `OnSelectTemplate`:

```
protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
{
}
```

By checking the type of the `item` argument, you should be able to figure out which template to return.

So lets say you have a `ViewModel` for `Dog` and one for `Cat` and want to show a different `DataTemplate` for each of those. You would do something like:

```
public class DogCatTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate DogTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate CatTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
    {
        if (item is DogViewModel)
            return DogTemplate;
        return CatTemplate;
    }
}
```

Then you can consume this in your XAML:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="dogTemplate">
            <ViewCell>
                ... <---- define your look of dog template here
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="catTemplate">
            <ViewCell>
                ... <---- define your look of cat template here
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
        <local:DogCatTemplateSelector x:Key="dogCatTemplateSelector"
            DogTemplate="{StaticResource dogTemplate}"
            CatTemplate="{StaticResource catTemplate}" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

Then simply set the `ItemTemplate` to your `dogCatTemplateSelector` instance you've defined in the resources on your `ListView`:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DogsCatsCollection}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource dogCatTemplateSelector}" />
```

Your `ViewModel` would then look something like:

```
public class Animal : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
}

public class DogViewModel : Animal
{
}

public class CatViewModel : Animal
{
}

public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Animal> DogsCatsCollection { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<Animal>();
}
```

Then you just populate `DogsCatsCollection` with instances of dogs and cats.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I implemented the same, it works fine. But how can I have a different height for dogTemplate and catTemplate? And How can I add another template with a horizontal scroll in it?

Comment: @VivekShah ListView has a property called HasUnevenRows. If you set this to true, then rendering engine will automatically calculate the height if each row and therefore your dog and cat templates can have different heights.

Comment: @JacobJoz Thanks, I have implemented it. It works fine. And for horizontal scroll, I took the ListView Inside ViewCell and it also works well.

Comment: @Cheesebaron that's a very good answer, well written and very clear :) Thank you