# Xamarin ViewCell subclass getting error in run time. "ViewCell Must Have a View"?

Tags: xamarin.forms, subclass

I am getting this runtime error saying that the CellView needs a View. I have not found anything on this so far, here on StackOverflow or on google, so I am in the total dark about what needs to be fixed.

I need to set up a list view with 2 sections. the first one is for the bikes that are in the database and the other section is for the ones that we detected but are not saved in the DB yet.

Both sections use the same UI (cell) and so I need to be able to have a sliding button (ContextAction MenuItem) in the first section and for the second section this action needs to be disabled/removed.

If it's not possible then I would need to have the action for the second section "Add" instead of "Forget".

This is why I created a subclass.

this is my code.
(edit: corections)
---- .xaml file ----

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
          x:Class="EGrid18.Components.BikeSelectionCell"
          x:Name="ThisCell">
    <ViewCell.View>
        <StackLayout>
            <Grid ColumnSpacing="10"
                  BindingContext="{x:Reference ThisCell}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="32"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Text="{Binding BikeName}"
                       StyleClass="bikecellname"                                       
                       Grid.Row="0"
                       Grid.Column="0"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                       HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                <Image Source="{Binding Image}"
                       HeightRequest="16"
                       WidthRequest="16"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                       Aspect="AspectFit"                                       
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       Grid.Row="0"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding Distence, StringFormat='{0:F2} M'}"
                       Grid.Row="0"
                       Grid.Column="2"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            </Grid>   
        </StackLayout>
    </ViewCell.View>
</ViewCell>
```

---- .cs file ----

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace EGrid18.Components
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class BikeSelectionCell : ViewCell
    {
        public static BindableProperty BikeNameProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BikeName), typeof(string), typeof(BikeSelectionCell), string.Empty);
        public string BikeName
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(BikeNameProperty);
            set => SetValue(BikeNameProperty, value);
        }
        public static BindableProperty ImageProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Image), typeof(string), typeof(BikeSelectionCell), string.Empty);
        public string Image
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(ImageProperty);
            set => SetValue(ImageProperty, value);
        }
        public static BindableProperty DistenceProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Distence), typeof(double), typeof(BikeSelectionCell), 0.0);
        public double Distence
        {
            get => (double)GetValue(DistenceProperty);
            set => SetValue(DistenceProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty ForgetCommandProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Command), typeof(ICommand), typeof(BikeSelectionCell), null);

        public ICommand ForgetCommand
        {
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(ForgetCommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ForgetCommandProperty, value); }
        }

        public Command OnForget => new Command(() => Execute(ForgetCommand));

        // Helper method for invoking commands safely
        public static void Execute(ICommand command)
        {
            if (command == null) return;
            if (command.CanExecute(null))
            {
                command.Execute(null);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            if(propertyName == nameof(Image))
            {                
                this.ContextActions.Clear();

                if (Image != "unknown")
                {
                    this.ContextActions.Add(new MenuItem()
                    {
                        Text = "Forget",
                        Command = ForgetCommand,
                        CommandParameter = this
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

--- the .xaml file that consumes the CellView subclass ---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:EGrid18.ViewModels"
    xmlns:iOS="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
    xmlns:components="clr-namespace:EGrid18.Components"
    iOS:Page.UseSafeArea="True"
    x:Class="EGrid18.Views.BikeSelectionPage"
    Title="Bike Selection List">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <vm:BikeListViewModel x:Key="vm"/>
            <StyleSheet Source="/CSS/Styles.css"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem x:Name="ScanButton" Text="Scan"
                     Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource vm}, Path=OnScanCommand}"
                     CommandParameter="{Binding Source={StaticResource vm}, Path=IsScanning}" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Margin="8,8,8,8">
            <Label Text="Bike Selection Page"
                   StyleClass="titlelabel"/>
            <ListView x:Name="ListView"
                      BindingContext="{StaticResource vm}"
                      StyleClass="listview"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding BikeList}"
                      IsGroupingEnabled="True"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBike}"
                      Margin="8,8,8,8">

                <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Heading}"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   Margin="8,8,8,8"/>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <components:BikeSelectionCell
                            BikeName="{Binding Name}"
                            Image="{Binding Image}"
                            Distence="{Binding Distence}"/>                            
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: The error stems from the closing of the tag. "/>" if I use <components:BikeSelectionCell
                            BikeName="{Binding Name}"
                            Image="{Binding Image}"
                            Distence="{Binding Distence}"/> <Lable Text=":( grrrr"/></components:BikeSelectionCell> .. the error is gone along with what I set inside the <CellView.View> :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was coming from a missing constructor that needed to initialize the Component.

```
public BikeSelectionCell()
{
     InitializeComponent();
}
```

In the end I used the suggestion ToolmakerSteve. I also used a custom DataTemplateSelector to set specifics DataTemplate for the 2 different sections

I am setting this as the answer for any one looking for this problem as the problem was really the missing call to `InitializeComponent();`

Answer (score 1):

A ViewCell is not a View - it isn't part of View heirarchy. It is a "wrapper" that is needed by ListView, around each item.
Personally, I *never* create subclasses of `ViewCell`, though that can be done.

IMHO, Its more straightforward to make a custom `View`, then wrap that in `<ViewCell>` to use with `ListView`.

As a View, you can inherit from any view class. If you don't know what else to use, inherit from `ContentView`. (Or from `StackLayout`, if need to add multiple children views.) In your case, your View is a StackLayout.

```cs
public partial class BikeSelectionView : StackLayout
... // All the lines of code you have in BikeSelectionCell go here.
```

xaml:

```xml
<StackLayout ... x:Name="ThisCell">
    <Grid ColumnSpacing="10" ...>
    ... All the remaining lines of code from your xaml ...
</StackLayout>
```

Usage inside ListView's ItemTemplate:

```xml
<DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>
        <components:BikeSelectionView
            BikeName="{Binding Name}"
            Image="{Binding Image}"
            Distence="{Binding Distence}"/>
    </ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
```

One advantage of this approach is if you switch from `ListView` to `CollectionView` (which does not use `ViewCell`s), you can still use the custom class:

```xml
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
         <components:BikeSelectionView ... />
    </DataTemplate>
</CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: This would solve the error I am getting.. But it will put me back to square 1 with my ContextAction problem.

Comment: Whatever you did in your ViewCell, you instead put those properties on the custom view. It behaves exactly the same. Though looking more closely at your xaml, not sure why that didn't work - I see you declare `ViewCell.View`. **Add to question** the xaml where that viewcell is used.

Comment: I've edited my answer, to make it clearer that it is straightforward to switch to the approach I show, retaining everything you did. OTOH I don't see any reason your logic wouldn't work. You might want to comment out usage of your custom cell, just put a standard viewcell there with a label - is it possible the error message is not from that line in the xaml?

Comment: I added a comment to my question. the error goes a way if in the ContentPage I did set some content to the my custom ViewCell "<components:BikeSelectionCell ...><Label Text="Not happy"/></components:BikeSelectionCell>", but problem is that the content I set in the <ViewCell.View> does not show.

Comment: Looking at this Question. and your answer. I think I have no other choice than to use a ContenView for my UI and add some DataTemplateSelector thing to get it working and have 1 section where the cell have an action and where the other section does not. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45832940/xamarin-forms-cross-platform-multiple-type-of-cells-in-listview

Comment: `and have 1 section where the cell have an action and where the other section does not` 
 Hi @PascaleBeaulac,   I don't quite understand what you mean. Have you resolved this problem?

Comment: ListView as 2 sections. first one the cell need to have a ContextAction. but not the ones in section 2. and yes I just finished fixing that. and I think I know now why my custom Cell was having an error. The constructor is missing along with the InitializeComponent call. XD